# I got Erreur When Show Name Status and Map Class 'Map' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\gel_back_end\resources\views\devices\index.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

```
class Device extends Model {
    protected $table ="devices";
    protected $fillable = ['name','description','serial','ip','x','y','level','map_id','status_id'];
    function map(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Map');
    }

    public function statu()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Status');
    }
}
```

//Model Status

```
    class Status extends Model
    {
        public function device()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Device');
        }
    }
```

// Model Map

```
    class Map extends Model
        {

            protected $fillable= ['name','path','width','height'];
            public function devices()
            {
                return $this->hasMany('App\Device');
            }
        }
```

//  DeviceController

```
    public function index()
            {
                return view('devices.index',[
                    'devices' => Device::all(),
                    'maps' => Map::all(),
                    'status' => Status::all()
                ]);
            }
```

// Inside Blade

```
           <table id="table_devices" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">#</th>
                          <th scope="col">Name</th>
                          <th scope="col">Description</th>
                          <th scope="col">Serial</th>
                          <th scope="col">IP</th>
                          <th scope="col">x</th>
                          <th scope="col">y</th>
                          <th scope="col">Level</th>
                          <th scope="col">Map</th>
                          <th scope="col">Status</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        @foreach ($devices as $device)
                          <tr>
                            <td>{{ $device->id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $device->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $statu->description ? $statu->description  : '--' }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $device->serial }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $device->ip }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $device->x }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $device->y }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $device->level }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $device->map->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $device->statu->name }}</td>
                          </tr>
                        @endforeach
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Can you include your `Map.php` file? (Including `namespace ...;`, at the top of the file)

Answer (score 0):

Change your map relationship,
`'App\Map'` or `Map::class`

Answer (score 0):

it worked for Map but i got new erreur about show name statu

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'statuses.device_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `statuses` where `statuses`.`device_id` = 2 and `statuses`.`device_id` is not null limit 1) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\gel_back_end\resources\views\devices\index.blade.php)